# C# Mono Soft debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, mono

I have SoftDebugger.dll and Mono.exe with source code of both.
I want to debug my c# application using Mono and softdebugger. Suppose i have one C# project TestDebug, in which code is there which I want to debug. How should I link

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted

Answer (score 4):

Mono's soft debugger isn't a stand-alone tool. You need to use it with [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com)

You may be able to use the 'hard debugger' called 'mdb' which is like many other command line debuggers. mdb's main advantage is that it can step into unmanaged code where the soft debugger can't.

In general, for a mono or .Net program to be debuggable, you must supply the `/debug` option to the compiler.

See also [Mono Debuggers](http://www.mono-project.com/Debugger) and [Using MDB](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aDebugger)